# Easy way to view promise chain in Angular? (View all functions that were/will be executed)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When reading somebody else's code, it's not always easy to know how values are modified in a promise chain.

For example, in an ajax request, there could be an `interceptor` that modifies the response value and some `then` that modifies it again before getting to the end of the chain.

Is there some easy way to view all the functions that have been executed in the chain and the next ones that will be?

Comment: Do you mean something at execution time, or some IDE plugin or the likes?

Comment: Don't know a way to look wich functions have been called on an value, unless they're on the call-stack, and there is no way to look what may/will happen with that value in the future. But this shouldn't be the problem, It should not be about how this value has been modified, but about what some particular codes expects as Input and what it returns; different state of mind. How it achieves this, should be secondary.

Comment: @ste2425, at execution time. Trying to understand why a function has a certain value even though an upstream `then` had a totally different value.

Comment: @Thomas, I'm supposed to fix bugs on somebody else's code and a function has a value that's completely different from the value returned by the http interceptor.  
There must be some bad code that modifies the value in between but I don't really know where.

Comment: @MrVoodoo In my experience there is no easy way to find/solve these bugs. You'll have to utilize the debugger and work backwards from the function you know, that it returns false values, until you find the reason for this.

Comment: @MrVoodoo not too sure if its still available but chrome had an experimental feature in devtools where you could ignore library code in its stack traces [heres info](https://divshot.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/ignoring-library-code-while-debugging-in-chrome/) if this still works you could hopefully stick a breakpoint at the end of your promise chain and only have a stack trace with your handlers and own code, not full of angulars stuff. Again its experimental so i don't know if its been removed or not but worth a look i guess. There is also the experimental promise inspector.

Comment: @ste2425, thank you for your answer. The experimental promise inspector is not yet compatible with angular's implementation of promises.  
And I can't just blackbox the library because the promise chain isn't a flat sequence of function calls, so the previous function that modified the value isn't a parent of the current function.  
That's why it's pretty complicated for me to debug this code.